# How Can I Tell If Microsoft Defender Has Scanned A Blob (a blob with no virus)

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps, azure-defender

I'm looking into using Microsoft Defender for Cloud to use with [Blob Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/defender-for-cloud/defender-for-storage-introduction).

Ideally I'd like to:

1. Upload to Storage
2. Have Defender for cloud scan for viruses
3. If there's an issue, remove it
4. If there's NOT an issue, process it further.

Step 3 is easy. [Workflow automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/defender-for-cloud/workflow-automation) and can easily trigger such events.

The bit I can't work out is: what if the scan goes through fine?

I've looked in Logic Apps and can't find a 'successfully scanned' trigger.

[image: logic app view for defender events]

When will the scan occur? As soon as uploaded, or just on a schedule?

Is there anything I can go on (metadata?) to know a blob has been scanned and is good to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft Defender for Storage does not currently scan uploaded files. You can read more about this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/defender-for-cloud/defender-for-storage-introduction#limitations-of-hash-reputation-analysis). This being the case you cannot accomplish what you are are trying to do with the current offering.
You have a couple of options:

1. Wait for the release of the malware scanning feature (this is in the works)
2. Use something like [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-av-automation)

Answer (score 1):

This is now available see [Malware scanning in Defender for Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/defender-for-cloud/defender-for-storage-malware-scan)

You can tell if a file has been scanned through [Blob Index Tags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-index-how-to)

The 2 tags you'd be interested in are `Malware Scanning scan time UTC` and `Malware Scanning scan result`

[image]