# How fast does Microsoft Defenfder for Cloud scan documents in a blob?

Tags: performance, azure-blob-storage, azure-defender

I am considering using Microsoft Defender on Cloud for Blob storage. A couple of things that I can't seem to find answers to are the following:

1. When does the scan occur?

- Does it scan immediately when the file is uploaded? Or on a schedule of some sorts?

2. How fast is the scan of the file?

- I understand that it uses a hash to compare the file to know viruses, but how long does this take?

I have already referenced this question: [How Can I Tell If Microsoft Defender Has Scanned A Blob (a blob with no virus)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70938817/how-can-i-tell-if-microsoft-defender-has-scanned-a-blob-a-blob-with-no-virus). However, the answer didn't quite get to the point of speed.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/defender-for-cloud/defender-for-storage-introduction#:%7E:text=Azure%20Defender%20for%20Storage%20is%20an%20Azure-native%20layer,Intelligence%20to%20provide%20contextual%20security%20alerts%20and%20recommendations.): "Security alerts are triggered for the following scenarios (typically from 1-2 hours after the event):", where hash reputation scanning is one of the scenarios.